# Mahout: (fast performance) how to write preferences to file?

Tags: java, performance, mahout, recommendation-engine

I have a training dataset of 800.000 records from 6000 users rating 3900 movies.
These are stored in a comma separated file like: `userId,movieId,preference`.
I have another dataset (200.000 records) in the format: `userId,movieId`. My goal is to use the first dataset as a training-set, in order to determine the missing preferences of the second set.

So far, I managed to load the training dataset and I generated user-based recommendations. This is pretty smooth and doesn't take too much time. But I'm struggling when it comes to writing back the recommendations.

The first method I tried is:

- read a line from the file and get the `userId,movieId` tuple.
- retrieve the calculated preference with `estimatePreference(userId, movieId)`
- append the preference to the line and save it in a new file

This **works, but it's incredibly slow** (I added a counter to print every 10.000th iteration: after a couple of minutes it had only printed once. I have 8GB-RAM with an i7-core... how long can it take to process 200.000 lines?!)

My second choise was:

- create a new `FileDataModel` with the second dataset
- do something    like this:

  `newDataModel.setPreference(userId, movieId, recommender.estimatePreference(userId, movieId));`

Here I get several problems:

1. at runtime: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (as I found [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.user/11330), `FileDataModel` actually can't be updated. I don't know why the function `setPreference` exists in the first place...)
2. The [API](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/) of `setPreference` states "This method should also be considered relatively slow."

I read around that a solution would be to use *delta files*, but I couldn't find out what that actually means. Any suggestion on how I could speed up my writing-the-preferences process?

Note that I'm new to Mahout and to recommender systems, so please use layman terms ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the problem is writing the results?  It seems to me that the real problem is the use of a user-based recommender.

For such a small data set, for instance, a search-based recommender will be able to make recommendations in less than a millisecond with multiple recommendations possible in parallel.  This should allow you to do 200,000 recommendations in a few minutes on a single machine.

With such a small dataset, indicator-based methods may not be the best option.  To improve that, try using something larger such as the million song dataset.  See http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/

Also, using and estimating ratings is not a particularly good thing to be doing if you want to build a real recommender.

Finally, questions about Mahout are much better addressed to the Mahout mailing list itself.

Comment: This is an assignment from a course so I must follow some constraints... I saw that you also answered me in the mailing list. I'll continue the discussion there. thank you!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since the discussion went on in the Mahout mailing list. For whoever stumbles upon this questions, one hint: the performance limitation is (I think) mostly due to the poor performance of the "estimatePreference" method